# Why can't new cloned hard drives be used in 2009 MBP 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, sata, bless

Ok strange one this and really can't figure it out.
Took out a dead 250gb apple (fujitsu) drive from 13" 2.53 intel core 2 duo
(mid 2009) model.

I cloned a copy of 10.6.8 using superduper to the new samsung 1TB 2.5" drive, test booted up via a sata/usb cable via the macbook pro and all working fine. My problem comes once the new drive is installed into the macbook pro it can't seem to boot from the 1TB drive at all. Disk utilities also does seems to be able to scan it correctly either and seems sluggish and it won't even let me format the drive via disk utilties either.

First I thought it was the new 1TB drive, but I've just had a 2nd drive delivered and cloned the same copy of 10.6.8 on to the 2nd new drive.
All boots fine via sata/usb cable then once installed in macbook pro it won't boot from the new drive. Tried holding alt to give boot options, it see drive and tries to boot but stops at apple logo.

Booted in via a clone of 10.9 on any external drive all boots fine and i can see the new internal 1TB drive. When I try to change the startup disk to the internal 1TB i get the drive is unable to be blessed. I know the drive is formated correctly and I know it boots via the sata/usb cable via the macbook pro.

My only think is there is something wrong with the sata cable to logic board on the macbook pro now? As any drive will boot with a system via usb, but once i install either of the x2 different new 1TB drives inside the macbook pro it won't boot and can't seem to format the drives either.

Any help would be greatful, not sure what i else i can do now?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the sata cable on this MBP, swapped out and put new sata cable in and boots the new 1TB drive totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

SuperDuper could be the problem here, I suggest trying [Carbon Copy Cloner from Bombich Software](https://www.bombich.com).

Comment: But why would the cloned drives boot fine via usb/sata cable and then not boot once installed in the Macbook Pro.

Comment: That is difficult to answer. Perhaps this new drive uses too much power for the MacBook Pro to handle during long periods. Have you compared the current required by the old drive vs the new one?